# continuous function on the reals with dense image in the complex plane

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be continuous with a dense image. How does one show that the preimage under $f$ of an open ball in $\mathbb{C}$ is unbounded?

Answer (score 2):

I don't thing the statement is correct. First, from every segment of length $>0$ to every square there exists a continuous surjective map ( say a [Peano curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve)). Now, consider a covering of the plane with squares in the form of a spiral. Cover the $n$th square with a map from $[n,n+1]$. Piece these maps together to cover the plane with $[0, \infty)$. Do the same for the other half $(-\infty, 0]$. The continous map thus obtained, from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is surjective, and moreover, for every unbounded set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ the set $f(A)$ is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. The same idea works I guess if I go from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ right?